# Not able to debug ant script in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ant

When I try to debug ant script by eclipse it get terminate as it come at debug point!!!!

Here is detail of error log

Message: Error logged from Ant UI:
Exception stack trace:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:384)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.launchConfigurations.RemoteAntBuildListener$ServerConnection.run(RemoteAntBuildListener.java:89)
```

Session Data:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_10
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically debug Ant by running it externally from Eclipse and connecting remotely.  I set my ANT_OPTS to include

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y
```

Then I just connect with Eclipse to the specified port.